# Execution order of closures

Tags: ios, swift, closures

Here's my code:

I'm just a beginner in programming with this language and I have a problem with a dynamic collection view

My problem is that the the first print is executed after the second one and I'm wondering why...

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
let db = Firestore.firestore()

let cellId: String = "cellId"

var news = [[String: Any]]()


override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()


    navigationItem.title = "Novità"

    sideMenu()
    customizeNavBar()

    collectionView?.register(NovitaCellView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning(){

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}



override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    db.collection("News").getDocuments(){(querySnapshot, err) in

        if let err = err{
            print("Errore: \(err)")
        }else{
            for document in (querySnapshot?.documents)!{
                let cell = document.data()
                self.news.append(cell)
                print ("document number: \(self.news.count)")
            }
        }

    }

    print("exe return with value: \(self.news.count)")
    return self.news.count
}
```

edit: I tried setting it into the viewDidLoad func as well as setting it both as a sync queue and an async queue and it either doesn't works.

edit 2: i made this working by adding the closure into a max priority queue and reloading the view after in the main thread but it takes a long time in order to work..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are going to `background thread` mode when you call `getDocuments` which have less priority than `Main thread`.So replace below part of code into `viewDidLoad` or a method which is called from `viewDidLoad`

```
db.collection("News").getDocuments(){(querySnapshot, err) in

    if let err = err{
        print("Errore: \(err)")
    }else{
        for document in (querySnapshot?.documents)!{
            let cell = document.data()
            self.news.append(cell)
            print ("document number: \(self.news.count)")
        }

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
          tableview.reloadData()
       }

    }

}
```

and when you get your data you go back to main thread and reload your `tableview` using this code.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

You can learn more about threading from [apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch) documentation and [this](https://www.appcoda.com/grand-central-dispatch/) tutorial also.

Comment: I tried setting it into the viewDidLoad func as well as setting it both as a sync queue and an async queue and it either doesn't works..
Help me pls

Comment: don't you remove the above mentioning code from 'numberOfItemsInSection'  method ??

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that this line

```
db.collection("News").getDocuments(){(querySnapshot, err) in
```

is asynchronous (runs in another queue other than the main queue ) it's a network request that will run after the below line (which runs in main queue)